# Linking a D program with a non-default druntime library

Tags: linker, dmd, druntime

How can I link my dmd-compiled program with a specific version of the druntime?

I need this when experimenting with a new GC. GC's are defined in druntime.

See also: https://forum.dlang.org/post/dahmztupviwgazbzevps@forum.dlang.org

Comment: If the runtime interface is not 100% stable, this might not be possible.

Comment: What about adding a new allocator in my main program and then registering it statically?